# Variable set using the set operator are not being propagated to the parent template in jinja

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

parent.sql

```
I am in parent {{ itable }}
```

child.sql

```
{% extends 'test.sql' %}

{% set itable = "test"  %}
```

When I run the my python code

```
template = env.get_template('child.sql')
    data = {
            'impressions_table': 'test'
        }
    j = jinjasql.JinjaSql(env=env)
    query, bind_params = j._prepare_query(
        template,
        data
    )
```

My output is

```
I am in test %s
```

This is a simple example for something complex I am doing I am looking for a way to propagate variable values up to parents.

I have also tried using

```
include
```

but I get an error saying expected end got with.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct - variables are not propagated to their parent scope. Blocks are however used to override behavior in parents:

parent template:

```
I am in parent {% block itable %}{% endblock %}
```

child template:

```
{% extends 'test.sql' %}

{% block itable %}test{% endblock %}
```

This also allows you to set a default value in the parent by having the default value inside the block: `{% block itable %}default_value{% endblock %}`

Comment: Is there a way I can propagate it to the parent?

Comment: That's what blocks are for.

Comment: So if I am trying to replace a variable by its name in the parent I would have to make that a block? There is no other way around it?

Comment: Blocks are how child templates puts content into parent templates, yes. That way you end up with explicit requests between the templates about which content can be overridden by child templates and don't end up with overwriting internal variables.